# Function template look-up issue

Tags: c++

Could someone please explain why the following code is giving error (`error C2065: 'select' : undeclared identifier`) at compile time:

```
namespace N { 
    class MyClass{ 

    }; 
    template<int I> void select(MyClass*)
    {}
}
void g (N::MyClass* mp) 
{ 
    select<10>(mp); 
}
void main()
{}
```

According to Argument Dependent Lookup, this should work fine, since I have specified `N::` in `g``s argument. So, select should be visible to compiler.

Why does ADL not work here?

Comment: This question already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953684/why-doesnt-adl-find-function-templates)

Comment: btw, it's `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`, even if you do not `return` anything (in which case it is the same as returning `0`)

Comment: "void main()" also works fine. I am working on VS 2008. May i know why have you explicitly mentioned it? It will be helpful for me if its important. Why main should return int?

Comment: @Anitesh: `main` should return `int` because that's the only portable return type specified by the language standard. Your compiler allows non-standard extensions, but most others don't. Posting non-standard code here makes the question harder to answer.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried N::select?
either that or a

```
using namespace N
```

should work since simply `select` is not visible

Comment: you cannot see it yet, but this  is the fourth answer that states _use `N::select`_. But this is not an answer to the question. The question was about why ADL does not work here.

Comment: I got my answer in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953684/why-doesnt-adl-find-function-templates). Please refer.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you utilise a class from a divergent namespace from the one you are currently in you must either reference it directly (`N::select`) or set up a using namespace (`using namespace N;`) or set up a direct using statement to it for future use (`using N::select`)

For disambiguation I would look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772759/how-to-disambiguate-namespace-and-class-with-identical-names) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) , which between them should give you  a good start on how/why you cannot simply call select.

Cheers, and feel free to get a hold of me for more info.